# how to run `mix ecto.migrations` for test db?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I found `MIX_ENV=test; mix ecto.migrations` or `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.migrations` not running for test db. It is still working for dev db.

How to run command correctly?

config/config.exs

```
# This file is responsible for configuring your application
# and its dependencies with the aid of the Config module.
#
# This configuration file is loaded before any dependency and
# is restricted to this project.

# General application configuration
import Config

config :mirror,
  ecto_repos: [Mirror.Repo]

# Configures the endpoint
config :mirror, MirrorWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  render_errors: [view: MirrorWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json), layout: false],
  pubsub_server: Mirror.PubSub,
  live_view: [signing_salt: "Vkhu6Ebn"]

# Configures the mailer
#
# By default it uses the "Local" adapter which stores the emails
# locally. You can see the emails in your browser, at "/dev/mailbox".
#
# For production it's recommended to configure a different adapter
# at the `config/runtime.exs`.
config :mirror, Mirror.Mailer, adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.Local

# Swoosh API client is needed for adapters other than SMTP.
config :swoosh, :api_client, false

# Configure esbuild (the version is required)
config :esbuild,
  version: "0.14.29",
  default: [
    args:
      ~w(js/app.js --bundle --target=es2017 --outdir=../priv/static/assets --external:/fonts/* --external:/images/*),
    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__),
    env: %{"NODE_PATH" => Path.expand("../deps", __DIR__)}
  ]

# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]

# Use Jason for JSON parsing in Phoenix
config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason

# Import environment specific config. This must remain at the bottom
# of this file so it overrides the configuration defined above.
import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"
```

config/test.exs

```
import Config

# Configure your database
#
# The MIX_TEST_PARTITION environment variable can be used
# to provide built-in test partitioning in CI environment.
# Run `mix help test` for more information.
config :mirror, Mirror.Repo,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  hostname: "localhost",
  database: "mirror_test#{System.get_env("MIX_TEST_PARTITION")}",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  pool_size: 10

# We don't run a server during test. If one is required,
# you can enable the server option below.
config :mirror, MirrorWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4002],
  secret_key_base: "A4Y3Ah4IlzIss5UAoOW189x9OqS+Hg3ft6CSOgQQM9BJNAeY05N88rtpb/oZqZLa",
  server: false

# In test we don't send emails.
config :mirror, Mirror.Mailer, adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.Test

# Print only warnings and errors during test
config :logger, level: :warn

# Initialize plugs at runtime for faster test compilation
config :phoenix, :plug_init_mode, :runtime
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant sections of your `config/config.exs` and `config/test.exs`? Elixir will just use whatever is declared for this environment.

Comment: I have added these two files.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe migrations already run so it just has nothing to do? (btw `mix test` is running migrations if needed: `test: ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate --quiet", "test"]`). Could you try `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset`?

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed `MIX_TEST_PARTITION`: you should probably run it for each value you need to migrate: `MIX_TEST_PARTITION=1 MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.migrate`

Comment: I have tried the partition. The response is as follows: `07:19:24.885 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.293.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 3D000 (invalid_catalog_name) database "mirror_test1" does not exist`

Comment: You probably forgot to run `mix ecto.create`. But as mentioned above, just running `mix test` should run all of these for you.

Comment: @sabiwara, I have drop and crate test db and do it again, it works now. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Great! I would recommend to replace `System.get_env` by [`fetch_env!`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#fetch_env!/1), this way it would avoid failing silently when you forget to pass the partition instead of running on a different test DB.